# Get unjoined values with dql

Tags: symfony, web, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

how can i get the unjoined values with dql ?
The problem in this code is that i'm getting only posts that have comments ..

```
public function getAllPostsDQL()
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p.type,p.date,p.urlImage,p.nom,u.nom as nomU,u.prenom as prenomU ,COUNT(co) as nb,MAX(co.date) as maxDate FROM PidevBundle:Publication p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           PidevBundle:Commentaire co WITH co.idPublication=p
           JOIN PidevBundle:User u WITH p.idUser=u
           ');

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Comment: What data exactly do you want to get from the DB using the query?

Comment: I have comments and posts with a many to one association , users and posts with another many to one association .
I want to display informations about the post like the name the date etc .. the number of coments , and the last coment's date .
it's for a forum that i m developping .

Comment: First of all you should try to use left join with user entity.

Something like this: `SELECT p.type,p.date,p.urlImage,p.nom,u.nom as nomU,u.prenom as prenomU ,COUNT(co) as nb,MAX(co.date) as maxDate FROM PidevBundle:Publication p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           PidevBundle:Commentaire co WITH co.idPublication=p
           LEFT OUTER JOIN PidevBundle:User u WITH p.idUser=u`

Comment: Problem persists :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for it , although i think it's a trash code :/
Thanks for everyone .
Code :

```
public function getAllPostsDQL()
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT 
                p.type,
                p.date,
                p.urlImage,
                p.nom,
                u.nom as nomU,
                u.prenom as prenomU,
                (SELECT COUNT(co.id) FROM PidevBundle:Commentaire co WHERE co.idPublication=p) as nb,
                (SELECT MAX(com.date) FROM PidevBundle:Commentaire com WHERE com.idPublication=p) as maxDate
                FROM PidevBundle:Publication p 
                INNER JOIN p.idUser u
                ');
    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (for Symfony3 syntax may need to be changed)

```
public function getAllPostsDQL()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('publication');
    $qb->select(array('publication.type', 'publication.date', 'publication.urlImage', 
                      'publication.nom', 'u.nom AS nomU', 'u.prenom AS prenomU', 
                      'COUNT(co.id) AS nb', 'MAX(co.date) AS maxDate'))
       ->leftJoin('p.idUser', 'u')
       ->leftJoin('p.idCommentaire', 'co');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: PidevBundle\Entity\Publication has no association named idCommentaire ...
That's because posts have comments and not the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public function getAllPostsDQL()
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT 
            p.type,
            p.date,
            p.urlImage,
            p.nom,
            u.nom as nomU,
            u.prenom as prenomU,
            COUNT(co.id) as nb,
            MAX(co.date) as maxDate 
        FROM PidevBundle:Publication p 
        LEFT JOIN p.idUser u
        LEFT JOIN PidevBundle:Commentaire co ON co.id = u.id
    ');

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Comment: got the same result as my first code :/ (PS: i had to change on by with)